# Images not loading when file is moved from one computer to the other

Tags: php

I have stored the links to images in a database so I can display them in my web application. The image folder is insider my project folder in htdocs. It works perfectly, but when I copy the project folder from the original htdocs and paste it in the htdocs of another computer, the images fail to load even though the path remains the same. I will be glad if the programmers here can explain to me what is happening. Thank you

here is the server response http://localhost:8080/folder/image/%2059f1c3840bf9b4.70759324.jpg Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
NB: %20 is not part of the image name. It is a space

Comment: you may want to edit your question with more details: if the database information is relevant to your question, which database? Is it also moved once you move the project? Why does the image name starts with the `%20` (space character)

Answer (score 0):

Either your path is off, or the other machine is not using port `8080`.

Most of the time, port `80` is the default, which does not need any port suffix.

You should try:

```
http://localhost/folder/image/%2059f1c3840bf9b4.70759324.jpg
```

and if that does not do it, then open your command line and

`cd path/to/localhost/folder/image/`

then
`pwd` to get the current folder path from that location.

It should also be noted that `%20` is a `" "` space character, and they tend to derp up file paths frequently. For ease of reference, try not to use file names with spaces for anything served on the web.